# How to pass image files in multipart/form-data request in android?

Tags: android, rest, android-volley, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload some images from android using a multipart/form-data post api. There are some form-data parameter texts in the body of request along with these image files. I am able to upload the text parameters but not the images. I have given the code I have tried using volley library. Please check and let me know if any solutions.

```
    public void uploadMultipart(){
    VolleyMultipartRequest multipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://testurl", new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            String resultResponse = new String(response.data);
            Log.e("resultResponse",resultResponse);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("data1", "1");
            return params;
        }
        @Override
        protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
            Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
            for(int i=0;i<imagesUpload.size();i++){
                Bitmap bitmap = imagesUpload.get(0);
                int size = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
                ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
                bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
                byte[] byteArray = byteBuffer.array();
                params.put("image"+(i+1), new DataPart("image"+(i+1)+".jpg",byteArray));
            }
            return params;
        }
    };
    Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(multipartRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to find a solution within your code, I recommend trying the code presented in this video. It provides a useful demonstration of how to send a file to a server using the multipart/form data format. You can find the video at the following link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbSAIuyHInY.
You will love it.